# Editing digits to find primes

Tags: number-theory, distribution-of-primes

Suppose that I am given a random, large (900+ digits) integer. I would like to edit a few of its digits so that the resulting integer is a prime. I am quite flexible on the definition of 'a few'. I would like the number to retain its length and as few edits as possible would be nice.

I would like to be able to find a prime as fast as possible. There are obvious things I should avoid:

- The last digit must be one of 1, 3, 7, 9
- The digit sum can't be a multiple of 3
- The alternating digit sum should not be a multiple of 11

Even with implementing these, this process will be very slow. Are there any other tricks that people have to offer?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize: as few edits as possible, or as fast an algorithm as possible?

Comment: Definitely the algorithm speed. I don't want the number of edits to be crazy (say more than 1% of the digits) though and preferably fairly evenly distributed throughout the number.

Comment: a pair of conditions to add to the ones you listed: primes are of the form $(6k+1)$ and $(6k-1)$.

Comment: Apart from trial division, you will need brute force. $900$ digits is still relatively small , so a few digits should be sufficient. Note that there is no efficient method to construct large primes, so some trial and error will be inevitable.

Comment: Also note that it can be time-consuming to prove a large number to be prime ($900$ digits is still routine) , unless you are content with a "probable prime".

Comment: You can use trial and error with the Baillie-PSW primality test to get a number that is (very) "probably prime". With PARI/GP, you can generate a primality certificate (i.e., a prime proof) for a 1000-digit number; this takes 5 minutes on my laptop, and 75 minutes on my Android phone.

Comment: @user25406: the first two bullet points in the OP are enough to ensure that the numbers are of the form $6k\pm1$.